# Storing info from UITextField back to detailTextLabel

Tags: ios, delegates

I have a tableViewCell that says Nickname and when you click on it, a segue takes you to a view controller with a text field where you can type a nickname, once you push the back button it should appear in the detailTextLabel of the main table view controller. I just keep getting an error I posted the code below where I get an error as well.

nickname text field code:

```
#import "NicknameViewController.h"

@interface NicknameViewController ()

@end

@implementation NicknameViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.delegate updateCarNickname:self.nicknameField];
}



@end
```

Here is the header file for the nickname view controller:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol CarNicknameDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)updateCarNickname:(UITextField *)updateNickname;
@end

@interface NicknameViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <CarNicknameDelegate> delegate;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nicknameField;

@end
```

In the main view controller I keep getting errors on this code and can't seem to figure it out:

```
-(void)updateCarNickname:(UITextField *)updateNickname {
    self.nicknameCell.detailTextLabel.text = updateNickname;
}
```

Before the segue begins I used this code:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"nicknameSegue"]) {
        NicknameViewController *controller = segue.destinationViewController;
        controller.delegate = self;
    }
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint when you call `updateCarNickname`, is your delegate set or is it nil? Second, see what `self.nicknameCell` is when it's supposed to be setting the text.

Comment: u gotta tell us the error too ..

Answer (score 0):

All views in a view controller gets deallocated once the view controller's dealloc is called.

You should change your `CarNicknameDelegate`'s parameter `UITextField` to `NSString`.

```
@protocol CarNicknameDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
- (void)updateCarNickname:(UITextField *)updateNickname;
@end
```

and change your `NicknameViewController` to something like this.

```
@interface NicknameViewController ()

@end

@implementation NicknameViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.delegate updateCarNickname:self.nicknameField.text];
}

@end
```